# Deleted Sec. Google Account. Now I'm stuck

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, delete, in-app-purchase, 2-step-verification

So basically, I wanted to make an inapp purchase, but my secondary useless account would always be the default account and it was unchangeable. After days of struggling I decided to simply completely delete the account, since I didnt use it anyway. Now however, I found out my phone is linked to this google account. Then I stumbled upon a thousand loopholes.

My phone asks me to verify my account in the notification bar. It can't be removed, so I decided to click on it. It brings me to a window where I have to login to my account to continue. I can't change whatever email is in the textbox, because there is simply nothing to type. I can't edit it. All it says is "can't find google account" and leaves me hanging. The problem is that that account doesn't even exist anymore. At all. So its constantly asking me to log in, and its bugging me.

So I decided to ignore the message. I went to settings/accounts and obviously all synchronisation failed, since the account was deleted. However, I can't remove the account from my phone *BECAUSE I HAVE TO LOGIN.* But there is no way to login because the account doesn't bloody exist.

So now Im stuck with an account linked to my phone that I dont even bloody use. I can't make inapp purchase because I constantly am forced to login to that same account that doesnt exist.

The app I'm trying to purchase is also simply showing errors and not allowing me to do anything. I can do all the standard stuff, but the verification notification is still there.

I can't install the app anymore on the playstore either. The playstore asks for verification whenever I try to install the app, and yeah, then it softlocks, because all I can click is "try again", which does nothing since it simply shows the same screen again.

I've been trying for so bloody long now. I'm completely done. There's so many goddamn issues the very simple problem being changing the standard account on my phone, which is practically impossible, since for anything I want to do I have to login to the deleted account.

Any help?

(I tried restarting my phone, btw)

Comment: Why don't you add a second account and use that for purchases. if the first account doesn't exist, make a new account with the same email address and then verify account. (Not sure the second option will work, but you can try.

Comment: Thats the thing, if I want to reverify, it simply asks for the account that doesnt exist anymore, before I can do anything else.

Comment: So I'm understanding that the account is still on the phone but doesn't exist anymore. So go into settings/accounts/Google press on the account and in the menu select 'remove' when you do that, there is no reason for it to ask for verification. If that doesn't work however go to Gmail.com 'create account' and make it the same email address and the same password as the one that you deleted.

Comment: just wondering which part worked for you? So i can post it as an answer, and others can benefit from it

Comment: Simply going to settings/accounts/google, selecting the account, presing the menu button next to the home button and selecting remove account. I didnt think of this before since the menu button is often useless.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm understanding that the account is still on the phone but you deleted the account from Google.com In that case go into settings>accounts>Google, press on the account and in the menu select 'remove'

You can then go ahead and add new accounts, by pressing add account.